# PHP MySQL not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have heard of this issue but can't seem to figure it out. I have the database and table names correct. I am not finding any errors and i even inserted a table myself on phpmyadmin that worked but when I tried to do it on my site it doesnt work. I even tested the connection..Not sure what to do now

Maybe someone can take a look at my code and see if they notice anything

```
<?php
if(mysql_connect('<db>', '<un>', '<pw>') && mysql_select_db('smiles'))
{

    $time = time();
    $errors = array();

    if(isset($_POST['guestbook_name'], $_POST['guestbook_message'])){
        $guestbook_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['guestbook_name']));
        $guestbook_message = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['guestbook_message']));

        if (empty($guestbook_name) || empty($guestbook_message)) {
            $errors[] = 'All Fields are required.';
        }
        if (strlen($guestbook_name)>25 || strlen($guestbook_message)>255) {
            $errors[] = 'One or more fields exceed the character limit.';
        }
        if (empty($errors)) {

            $insert = "INSERT INTO 'guestbook'VALUES('','$time','$guestbook_name','$guestbook_message')"; 
            if($insert = mysql_query($insert)){
                header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            } else{
              $errors[] = 'Something went wrong . Please try again.';
            }
        } else {
            foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo '<p>'.$error.'</p>';
            }
        }

    }
    //display entries
} 
else {
    'Fixing idiot';
}
      ?> 
      <hr />
       <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="POST">
     <p>Post Somethign</p>
      <br />
          Name:<br /><input type="text" name="guestbook_name" maxlength="25" />
   <br />
    Message:
    <br />
           <textarea name="guestbook_message" rows="6" coles="30"maxlength="255"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors?. What is the output?

Comment: You may want to also check for the exact errors you are getting, whether it would be syntax, connections, etc. For debugging, add mysql_error() instead of a generic message for your $errors array.

Comment: if you want to quote table and columnnames, use a tacktick ` not normal quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Remove quotes from table name 'guestbook' and leave a space between it and `values`

Answer (score 2):

Table name doesn't need quotes and supossing you're using id autoincrement, don't insert an empty string. So it should be:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES('$time','$guestbook_name','$guestbook_message')";
```

Also, take a look at your $time value. What MySQL data type is?

After the insert, try to display the mysql error:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('<db>', '<un>', '<pw>');
mysql_query($insert)
if (mysql_errno($conn)){
   $errors[] = mysql_error($conn);
}else{
   header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

EDIT: The hole snippet should be similar to:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('<db>', '<un>', '<pw>')
if( $conn && mysql_select_db('smiles')) //Note $conn
{

    $time = time();
    $errors = array();

    if(isset($_POST['guestbook_name'], $_POST['guestbook_message'])){
        $guestbook_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['guestbook_name']));
        $guestbook_message = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['guestbook_message']));

        if (empty($guestbook_name) || empty($guestbook_message)) {
            $errors[] = 'All Fields are required.';
        }
        if (strlen($guestbook_name)>25 || strlen($guestbook_message)>255) {
            $errors[] = 'One or more fields exceed the character limit.';
        }
        if (empty($errors)) {
            mysql_query($insert)
            $insert = "INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES('$time','$guestbook_name','$guestbook_message')"; 
            if (mysql_errno($conn)){
               $errors[] = mysql_error($conn);
            }else{
               header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            }
        } else {
            foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo '<p>'.$error.'</p>';
            }
        }

    }
    //display entries
}
```

Comment: when I stuck this under the insert i got an T_if errorr for if (mysql_errno($conn)){ line for somereason..

Comment: Do you have the $conn variable defined? I paste your snippet below.

Comment: that snippet you mentioned.If you dont mind what is it actually doing?I'm rather a beginner Thanks in advance

Comment: It's the first part of yours! Just switch them.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below query for insertion:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES('','{$time}','{$guestbook_name}','{$guestbook_message}')";
```