# Database connection successful but not able to insert data into database using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been struggling for about a week now and still have not got any results. I have read the following questions:

- [Unable to insert form data in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022228/unable-to-insert-form-data-in-mysql-database)
- [Connection to database seems successful but INSERT INTO sends no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043628/connection-to-database-seems-successful-but-insert-into-sends-no-data)
- [PHP MySQL not inserting into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393951/php-mysql-not-inserting-into-database)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/435746/unable-to-send-data-to-mysql-database-it-is-not-taking-by-my-php-code

I tried everything suggested in the above questions' answers. After reviewing my code, if you still think that the above questions' solution relates then please do tell.

My code - 
connect.php -

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "practice_user";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error;
} 
 else {
   echo "Success"; 
}

//Insert data into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO simple_login (name,email) VALUES('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}','{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}')";


$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

if(!$insert)
{
   echo $mysqli->error;
}



$mysqli->close();
```

register.html -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
       <form action="connect.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

As usual I am getting a "Successful" message for connection. Also it is not outputting any error message(if I have not appropriately tried to output insertion error in the given code, please do tell in the comments).

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Have you considered adding any error checking on your query? How about binding the parameters instead of using `real_escape_string()`?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but doesn't - echo $mysqli->error; output the required error?

Comment: $mysqli is undefined..? Shouldn't you be using $con->query($sql); ?

Comment: If you were doing the error checking properly you would have seen an error that points to what @skh is saying.

Comment: @skh I am so sorry, I didn't realize my mistake. Still a beginner. Yes it worked, of course. How do I close this question?

Comment: You shouldn't close. Upvote and accept @skh's answer below.

Comment: Did that already. But now I am getting downvotes which anyways doesn't affect my 1 reputation.

Comment: Make sure to check the check mark next to the answer when time allows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post this here, we all make mistakes so don't worry! As suggested your **$mysqli** function is undefined, you've stored your mysqli instance as the **$con** variable, so you should refer any mysqli functions on that.

Examine http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php for more information!

Comment: Yes I got that. Thank you very much. I should have tried harder and not asked this actually.

Comment: Not a problem, happens all the time! It's good to get other peoples eyes on things after staring at them for so long. Obvious issues are always the easiest to miss! :-)